# sklearn: Remove majority class at random without shuffling dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I have an image data-set of 48000 where 40k- normal class and 8k-abnormal instances. In order to make dataset balance, I need to undersample the majority class. Although I have used sklearn imblearn random undersampling method which works fine,but I need to preserve the order of the rows (image sequence) while removing the majority instances.